# Insert a custom block into another custom block, in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks

I have a block in my homepage site which has a div with a pair of banners.
I've created a new block only dedicated to my 2 images that I want to insert into my homepage block.

Is that possible? How can I do through my admin console, in block section?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure that I understand what you want to do, but if you've created a block with html, and you're trying to insert it on the homepage, create a widget, add the block to the widget, then in the layout updates section, choose homepage - main content area

[image]

[image]